# Getting error while using Imagemagick npm

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I am using Imagemagick npm in node to compress an image. I installed the npm module and it was working fine. But after some time, it throws the error shown below.

```
TypeError: currentLine.search is not a function
```

If I install the module again, it doesn't show the error. But again after some time, it throws the same error. I am using 0.1.3 version of Imagemagick with 8.9.1 version of node. 
Can any one help me with this issue?

Comment: There is no such  0.1.3 version of imagemagick.  Perhaps you meant 7.0.1.3. In that case, your node may be expecting ImageMagick 6 and not ImageMagick 7. Try uninstalling IM 7 and reinstall IM 6.

Comment: i checked in my package.json file it is 0.1.3  the imagemagick npm version

Comment: I have already IM 6 installed in my system

Comment: What is the version of IM 6.x.x.x? `convert -version` or `magick -version` for IM 7.x.x.x. There is no ImageMagick 0.1.3

Comment: I am using 6.7.5 version of imagemagick

Comment: Sorry I cannot help further. I do not know Node nor npm. ImageMagick 6.7.5 is over 250 versions old. But that may not be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same issue for 0.1.3 npm version. After some debugging, I found that if we add custom functions into `Array.prototype` like this

```
Array.prototype.asyncforEach = async function(cbk) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) await cbk(this[i], i, this);
};
```

Which will leads to an error in file `node_modules/imagemagick/imagemagick.js` at line number 113 `i` will have `asyncforEach` as a value so we have to change our `Array.prototype.methodName` like below or [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) this for better understanding.

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'asyncforEach', {
  value: async function(cbk) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) await cbk(this[i], i, this);
  }
});
```